# Java: Loop through JSON string (cant convert to JsonArray (gson)

Tags: java, json, loops, gson

i get a json object via an api:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject users = gson.fromJson(reader, JsonObject.class)
```

this is my json object:

```
{"users":"[{\"user_id\": \"100011\", \"name\": \"Tim Clark\"}, {\"user_id\": \"100083\", \"name\": \"Timmy Kent\"}]"}
```

and i try to loop through all users

```
    JsonArray usersArray = users.getAsJsonArray();
    for (JsonElement ua : usersArray) {
        JsonObject ua = ua.getAsJsonObject();
        String name = ua.get("name").getAsString();
        System.out.println(name);
    }
```

also tried this

```
    JsonArray usersArray = users.get("users").getAsJsonArray();
    for (JsonElement ua : usersArray) {
        JsonObject ua = ua.getAsJsonObject();
        String name = ua.get("name").getAsString();
        System.out.println(name);
    }
```

But I get always exceptions like this

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Array: "[{\"user_id\": \"100011\", \" ....
```

In my opinion it is a valid json array, what to I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JsonArray is between quotes: it's evaluated as a String

```
{"users":[{\"user_id\": \"100011\", \"name\": \"Tim Clark\"}, {\"user_id\": 
\"100083\", \"name\": \"Timmy Kent\"}]}
```

should work (quotes inside the array don't need to be escapted as well, like "users")